# Parsing csv in c++ exit code 11

Tags: c++, csv, parsing

I have an annoying problem with my program when I build it I have no error but when I run it the terminal write "Process finished with exit code 11" instead of printing element of a vector (in fact it is a void but I launch it in my main)

Thanks in advance.

```
void getData2 (ifstream& infile, Stock stocks[], int dataSize)

string token ;

const char delim = ',';

for ( int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++)
{
    getline(infile, stocks[i].date, delim);
    infile >> stocks[i].open ; infile.ignore(10, delim);
    infile >> stocks[i].high ; infile.ignore(10, delim);
    infile >> stocks[i].low ; infile.ignore(10, delim);
    infile >> stocks[i].close ; infile.ignore(10, delim);
    infile >> stocks[i].volume ; infile.ignore(10, delim);
    infile >> stocks[i].ajdclose ; infile.ignore(10, delim);

}

for ( int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++)
{
    cout << stocks[i].open;
}
```

Comment: May we see the file you're reading from

Comment: And the rest of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restating my response as an actual answer:

Normally a c++ program would look more like:

```
int main()
{
    // code
    return 0;
}

void getData2(ifstream& infile, Stock stocks[], int dataSize)
{
    // Get the data
}
```

The error 11 could be a segfault as the code does not have the expected entry point to start up.

Answer (score 0):

Sure

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() 

struct  Stock 
     string date;
     double open;
     double high;
     double low;
     double close;
     long volume;
     double ajdclose;
;

void getData2(ifstream& infile, Stock stocks[], int dataSize);

ifstream infile("/Users/emmanl/CLionProjects/ING.csv");

if (!infile) {
    cout << "File not open\n";
    return 1;
}

//stock vector init
Stock stocks[] = {};

//size to automate
const int Sizefile = 22;

//get data from yahoo files and input in struct
getData2(infile, stocks, Sizefile);


return 0;
```

Comment: Normally a c++ program would look more like
```
    int main()
    {
         // code
         return 0;
    }

   void getData2(ifstream& infile, Stock stocks[], int dataSize)
   {
        // Get the data
   }

The error 11 could be a segfault.

Comment: If you could be kind enough to flag my re-stated answer as the answer, I'd appreciate it.